# PHP : Send an UDP broadcast message , and wait the response

Tags: php, arduino, udp, broadcast

I used this code to send an UDP broadcast message

```
$ip = "255.255.255.255";
$port = 8888;
$str = "DEVICE_DISCOVERY";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); 
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1); 
socket_sendto($sock, $str, strlen($str), 0, $ip, $port);

socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 20, 0, $ip, $port);
echo "Messagge : < $buf > , $ip : $port <br>";

socket_close($sock);
```

I want that some specific network devices (in my case is some **Arduino** boards with ethernet shield) respond with a particular message.

The code works, but in this way i can't print all the responses but only one.

Comment: Eh, so, you mean you want to use a loop?

Comment: Sure of course, but in this case i don't know how to use it

Comment: Is your return data in a array? use `foreach(){}`, find out what form of data your response is turned in and then use the appropriate loop.

Comment: the response is a string

Comment: Show us the string then

Comment: Every device response with a string , a very simple string , like "abc" . The problem is not the type of the response , but how "listen" all the responses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a while loop, from which you break if there's no response within timeout.

First set timeout, eg 5 seconds:

```
socket_set_option($sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,array("sec"=>5,"usec"=>0));
```

And the loop:

```
while(true) {
  $ret = @socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 20, 0, $ip, $port);
  if($ret === false) break;
  echo "Messagge : < $buf > , $ip : $port <br>";
}
```

Full code:

```
$ip = "255.255.255.255";
$port = 8888;
$str = "DEVICE_DISCOVERY";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); 
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1);
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>5, "usec"=>0));
socket_sendto($sock, $str, strlen($str), 0, $ip, $port);

while(true) {
  $ret = @socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 20, 0, $ip, $port);
  if($ret === false) break;
  echo "Messagge : < $buf > , $ip : $port <br>";
}

socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: I had already seen this solution , would be fine if I could set these options: socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1);

Comment: You can, `SO_RCVTIMEO` is extra, not instead of `SOL_SOCKET`.

Comment: if i do this : `socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>10,"usec"=>0));` the timeout works , but not the broadcast message , if i do this : `socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, array("sec"=>10,"usec"=>0));` nothing works